# How to using Flutter Getx pass the model class data to controller and insert the data into firebase through tapping the button in main widget?

Tags: flutter, firebase, controller, crud, flutter-getx

I am a **new flutter learner** and I need some helps.  Anyone know **how to use getx to perform CRUD with the model class to Firebase Firestore ?**  There seems did not have much info on it, any references on it, appreciate those help, thank you. **How can I pass the data to controller and insert the data into firebase through tapping the button?**

Below is the model class:

`````
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? note;
  int? isCompleted;
  String? date;
  String? startTime;
  String? endTime;
  int? color;
  int? remind;
  String? repeat;

  Task({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.note,
    required this.isCompleted,
    required this.date,
    required this.startTime,
    required this.endTime,
    required this.color,
    required this.remind,
    required this.repeat,
  });

  // "key":"value"
  // adding to Firestore
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'note': note,
      'isCompleted': isCompleted,
      'date': date,
      'startTime': startTime,
      'endTime': endTime,
      'color': color,
      'remind': remind,
      'repeat': repeat,
    };
  }

  // field : value
  factory Task.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Task(
      id: map['id'] as int,
      title: map['title'] as String,
      note: map['note'] as String,
      isCompleted: map['isCompleted'] as int,
      date: map['date'] as String,
      startTime: map['startTime'] as String,
      endTime: map['endTime'] as String,
      color: map['color'] as int,
      remind: map['remind'] as int,
      repeat: map['repeat'] as String,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Task.fromJson(String source) =>
      Task.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);
}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a controller class that extends GetxController. This controller will handle the data and interaction with Firebase. For example:

   ```
    import 'package:get/get.dart';

    class FirebaseController extends GetxController {
      // Define your data variables and Firebase references here

      void insertDataToFirebase(String data) {
        // Implement your logic to insert the data into Firebase here
      }
    }
   ```
2. Add a button widget to your UI, and use the onPressed callback to call the controller's method to insert the data into Firebase. For example:

   ```
    class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    final FirebaseController firebaseController = Get.put(FirebaseController());

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('My Screen'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Insert Data'),
              onPressed: () {
                // Get the data you want to insert (e.g., from text fields)
                String data = 'Example data';

                // Call the controller's method to insert the data into Firebase
                firebaseController.insertDataToFirebase(data);
              },
            ),
      ),
    );
    }}
   ```

you can also pass your model in `insertDataToFirebase` like:

```
 void insertDataToFirebase(Task data) {
    // Implement your logic to insert the data into Firebase here
  }
```